# Windows 7: Boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

I've recently resized/moved the C partition, and then I had this problem on boot:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc0000225

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

I've tried to repair it with the Windows 7 installation disk, but it fails.

Comment: Sometimes you need to repeat the repair process (sometimes several times) for Windows to fully repair the errors.

Comment: The problem is that when it finds the installed Windows 7 version, the partition size is 0 Mo and the partition name is unknown.

Comment: What program did you use to resize/move the partition?

Comment: I used  `EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows failed to boot because the `C:\` patition where it's installed was damaged.I've tried `CHKDSK /R /X` as suggested by @Unix in his answer but it looks like the format is not `NTFS` anymore but `RAW`.

My other [question](https://superuser.com/questions/699445/change-raw-partition-to-ntfs-or-recover-files-from-raw) on how to change `RAW` to `NTFS` helped me to repair the damaged partition and Windows now boots normallay.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into a UBCD and run

```
CHKDSK /R /X
```